# Making active hyperlink bold and underline asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I am working on an asp.net page. I have two hyperlinks and I want to make them active ( apply a style sheet, make bolder and underline) but somehow it is not doing it.

Here is html:

```
   <li style="margin-left: 10px">
      <asp:Literal ID="ltrlRegiosn" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: HRGELoggedOutMaster, Language %>"></asp:Literal>:
    </li>
    <li class="active1"> <asp:HyperLink ID="Lang1HyperLink" runat="server" /></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="Lang2HyperLink" runat="server" /></li>
```

and style sheet is:

```
  <style>
        .active1{
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    </style>
```

and here is how i am trying to do it using code behind:

```
  if (Page.CurrentLanguage == 1)
            {
                Lang2HyperLink.CssClass = "active1";
                Lang2HyperLink.Font.Bold = true;
                Lang2HyperLink.Font.Underline = true;              
            }
            else
            {
                Lang1HyperLink.CssClass = "active1";
                Lang1HyperLink.Font.Bold = true;
                Lang1HyperLink.Font.Underline = true;               
            }
```

With this code, it becomes underlined but not bold.

Here is output html:

```
<li class="active1"> <a id="ctl00_ctl00_languageSwitcher_Lang1HyperLink" href="/AllVacancies.aspx?lang=2">Рус</a></li>

<li class="active1"><a id="ctl00_ctl00_languageSwitcher_Lang2HyperLink" class="active1" href="/AllVacancies.aspx?lang=1" style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Eng</a></li>
```

Please suggest how to fix it ?

Comment: Which web browsers are you testing this in? I have copied the content from your output html section directly into a new html file. It appears to be working in IE8 and also Firefox. The 2nd link is bolded and underlined, and the 1st link is underlined only, but not bolded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to set the style properties using code behind. when you are already setting the CssClass.  Just modify your CSS:

```
.active1
{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

And then you can set just the CssClass via code behind:

```
if (Page.CurrentLanguage == 1)
{
    Lang2HyperLink.CssClass = "active1";             
}
else
{
    Lang1HyperLink.CssClass = "active1";          
}
```

One more thing: I noticed that you have set the "Active1" class on your `<li>` as well:

```
<li class="active1">
```

That seems like it might be a typo, or at the very least will be confusing for you.  I would remove that.

Comment: I tried above code but only underline is effecting and text is not getting bold even with !important.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow Have you used the developer tools / inspector for your browser to see if there is some other CSS rule overriding your `text-decoration:underline;` with `text-decoration:none;`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked after removing code behind and using only css, removing li class.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow Great!  I'm glad I was able to help =)